# Potential Home Grounding Issue - Illinois

Tags: electrical, safety, grounding

I recently bought a new manufactured home.  There are instances where people have touched the front door and received an electric shock.  Using a non-contact voltage detector, I confirmed that there is detectable voltage present. Using my meter, I see 72V from the frame to ground.

I have an outside meter on a pole, a disconnect box underneath it, and have wiring in sch 80 electrical pvc conduit running under my house feeding up into the breaker box.

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

I asked a friend to come and look, and he suggested that I needed a ground wire from the outside disconnect to the inside breaker box.  I have a grounding rod connected to the outside disconnect and 3 wires running through the conduit (2 hot, 1 neutral) into the house.  There is also a bare copper wire running from the grounding bar in the breaker box that is lugged to the frame under the house.

My first thought was that a screw in the door facing had nicked a wire.  After removing every screw, that does not appear to be the cause.  Likewise, the problem seem intermittant and isn't experienced on other doors in the house.

Do I need a grounding wire from between the breaker box and the outside disconnect?  If so, would I achieve the same thing by running a ground wire from the breaker box to a different grounding rod since it will be ridiculuously hard to try and feed an extra wire back through the conduit now?

Comment: If you turn off the main disconnect does the voltage on the frame go away?

Comment: Yes. I am not drawing electricity from an outside source.

Comment: In your panel enclosure, are the grounded (neutral) and grounding bus bars connected together (bonded)?

Comment: Tester101: From what I see inside the breaker box, the neutral and ground buses are separate. WarLoki: if I understand your logic, using one breaker at a time to identify and isolate the circuit will tell me 1) if it is related to a particular circuit, and 2) if so, which one I need to look at? What do you mean by a "bad wire"?

Comment: @Nemesis Could you include a photo of the inside of the panel?  If the grounded (neutral) is not bonded to the grounding bar, and you're supplied by a 3 wire feeder. Then your grounding conductors are floating, and have no real reference to "ground". When you said you measured 72 volts from the door frame to ground, what were you using as ground?

Comment: When you say "*manufactured home*" do you mean "*mobile home*", or is it truly a manufactured home?

Comment: I think the two get used interchangeably (mobile/manufactured).  This one is on a permanent foundation - blocks, not underpinning.  72v from door to dirt.  I'll try and post a picture.

Comment: Ok.  No idea how to get the pictures I took posted.  I'd be happy to text or email them.  There is a neutral bus and a ground bus on each side of the breaker box.  I did not see any neutrals going to a ground bus on either side.  The are separate.

Comment: Re. pictures: Click edit. Click the rectangle at the top with the little mountains in it. @Tester101 - What would an unbonded neutral have to do with the door being live?

Comment: @Nemesis Are you saying that you put one probe from your meter on the door frame, and stick the other in the dirt!?

Comment: @Mazura This sentence "*There is also a bare copper wire running from the grounding bar in the breaker box that is lugged to the frame under the house.*", makes me think this is more of a *mobile home* than a *manufactured home*.  If ground is floating, than anything that is "*grounded*" could surely have an electrical potential difference with the electrical system.

Comment: @Mazura Though it sounds like the point may be moot, because I think the OP is sticking his probe in the actual **ground**.

Comment: If you prefer the term "mobile home" so be it.  When I say to "dirt" I mean porch railing - which is aluminum and in the dirt.

Comment: Pictures:  working from mobile phone.  Let me try at a desktop today.

Comment: @Nemesis I don't know what type of structure it is, I'm speculating based on the limited information provided. Also... The dirt is not a solid electrical ground, unless your meter's probe is 10' long 1/2" solid copper rod, and you've driven it 8' into the ground. You're measuring the voltage potential between the porch railing and the door frame, which could be anything.

Comment: @Tester101  Fair enough.  Still can't add pictures.  Not sure why as I'm using desktop now.  Anyway, my next thought is this:  If I have a floating neutral, wouldn't I see a significant voltage between my ground buss and neutral buss?  And if that's the case, I would assume that I need to run a ground wire from my outside disconnect to the breaker box inside.  I would probably wire up a test wire without drawing it through the conduit first to see if that solves the issue.  I have a bad feeling trying to fish a ground through the PVC is going to be a bag-smacker.

Comment: So, after testing last night, there is about 7.5V between neutral and ground in the breaker box.  This means a floating neutral, right?  So, my understanding is that I need to bite the bullet and pull a ground wire through the conduit and run it into my breaker box to solve the issue.  Would anyone disagree?

Comment: Issue solved.  A great big thank you to everyone that helped steer me in right direction!  Your support is much appreciated.

Comment: @Nemesis You should post an answer to your own question, detailing exactly what solved the problem and steps you took to diagnose it.  This could be helpful to future readers.

Comment: By the way @Nemesis, it's not a floating neutral, it's a floating ground. The grounded (neutral) conductor is grounded at the disconnect, it's the equipment grounding conductors in the panel that are not grounded (or at least that's what it sounds like).

Answer (score 4):

Turn off all the breakers, try them one at a time and see when the voltage returns, this should help to locate the problem area. Once you have the area found, turn on all the breakers, except  the breaker to that area, and check it again. Now with the problem breaker/breakers off, go through the devices and check if any have a bad wire. I would start with the switches that controls the outside light.

Answer (score 1):

You think you've found all the nails-through-wires, but there's one more.  I once had a friend who's garage light switches suddenly started operating different lights, and I traced it to a 16p nail that a roofer had put through two separate runs of wire, one of which was a three-way switch send, and the other a regular single send.  The nail shorted one leg of the three-way to the other wire's hot.  And yes, it was getting hot!

Comment: If this floating neutral search doesn't work out, I'm going to have to start searching one breaker at a time.